# Can we implement levenberg_marquardt optimizer in tf.keras.sequential compiler?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am using NN for prediction of Fe grades for a given input location coordinates. The total data is divided into training data = 3495 points and test data = 617 data points.

[Input and output data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUrBB.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71DVx.jpg)

```
ann = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units =25, activation = 'gelu'))

ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units =15, activation = 'gelu'))

ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units =10, activation = 'gelu'))

ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1))

ann.compile(optimizer= 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics = ['mae','RootMeanSquaredError'])

history = ann.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size = 32, epochs = 500, validation_split=0.10, shuffle= True)
```

I would like to implement Levenberg_marquardt optimizer instead of 'adam'.
Can we do it directly in here? If not how should I proceed if I want to use this optimizer algorithm?

Comment: For the next time, please spend a minute to see how to properly format your code snippets (done it for you  now).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but definitely not an easy task. See the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer#creating_a_custom_optimizer_2) to see how to do it.

> Creating a custom optimizer
> If you intend to create your own optimization algorithm,
> simply inherit from this class and override the following methods:

`_resource_apply_dense` (update variable given gradient tensor is dense)

`_resource_apply_sparse` (update variable given gradient tensor is sparse)

`_create_slots` (if your optimizer algorithm requires additional variables)

`get_config` (serialization of the optimizer, include all hyper parameters)

If you're looking for additional optimizers that you can pass directly, you can look at [`tensorflow_addons`](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/optimizers/LAMB)